# Can't receive any outside mail in bigrock webmail (sending from Gmail doesn't end up in the inbox)

Tags: email, webmail

I've created multiple email accounts @my-domain using cPanel in bigrock. These addresses can send mail successfully to each other and also to any other email account outside my domain (like Gmail).

But all emails @my-domain can only receive an email from each other not from outside my domain. That is, if I send an email from my Gmail to my @my-domain account it doesn't appear in my @my-domain account webmail inbox.

Why is this happening and what's the solution?

Comment: I'd be doing a DNS reset in cpanel.  See if that solves it - it might take a few hours to propagate.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm facing a similar issue.